FussionPBX menu bar
friends
I am currently working on translating FusionPBX into my native language. However, I've encountered an issue where the menu bar disappears when I switch to the translated language.
Could anyone help me identify the possible reasons behind this problem?
I tried to find relevant words (as Menu, Home, Settings and etc.) into app_languages_php files, but without any results.
